# Refactor: Replace with Constant String.Empty

Tags: vb.net, refactoring, devexpress

I have the following line of code

```
Dim a As String = ""
```

and the Refactor suggests replacing the `""` with `String.Empty`

It is a kind of Reafactoring but why? Since i am a newbie in the future declarations of mine should i better use the `String.Empty` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly a matter of preference really. Personally, I find String.Empty more clearly shows the programmer's intent (for example, that he didn't accidentally put an empty string instead of a space)... that's probably why "Refactor" suggests it. But other than that, they're exactly the same thing. Do as you see fit on this one.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the [String.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx) field is the zero-length string, "".

In application code, this field is most commonly used in assignments to initialize a string variable to an empty string. To test whether the value of a string is either null or String.Empty, use the IsNullOrEmpty method.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: @SashaGoldshtein, I told him through my explanation that using String.Empty is equal to use "" and String.Empty will assigns a proper initialization of an Empty string to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much a matter of personal preference. I prefer using constants whenever possible, especially so if they are already provided by the framework I'm using. I wouldn't go out of my way to eliminate every use of "" in the code. (Especially since the compiler will fold all repetitions of a string literal and keep only one of them for runtime.)

Answer (score 0):

"" potentially creates a new String object, while String.Empty refers to a predefined (existing) object. It's a minor nitpick, but that's what refatoring tools do: find all kinds of issues, inluding minor nitpicks.

Answer (score 0):

I always go the opposite and set the string to `null`. There are really a few situations where want you want to mean with "" is that you have a string built but with no content. Usually what you mean is that you have the string unbuilt. That's why I prefer the `null` construct.